# Data type mismatch in criteria expression only when using Group by Clause

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by

I have a very simple query, but i keep getting this error as soon i add a group by clause. The type of field is short text. I googled a lot but doesn't seem to find any solution. Data type in Excel is General and in access is Short Text.

```
SELECT Marketics.Case, Count(Marketics.[Prior Insurance]) AS [CountOfPrior Insurance]
FROM Marketics
GROUP BY Marketics.Case
HAVING (((Count(Marketics.[Prior Insurance]))="LOYA INS CO"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its normal,

You have  Count(Marketics.[Prior Insurance])="LOYA INS CO" ;
Count returns number and you are comparing it with text.

You should do

```
SELECT Marketics.Case, Count(Marketics.[Prior Insurance]) AS [CountOfPrior Insurance]
FROM Marketics
GROUP BY Marketics.Case
HAVING Count(Marketics.[Prior Insurance] ="LOYA INS CO");
```